# What number is missing?

Tags: number-sequence, science, chemistry

This is a sequence, that if transformed correctly, gives a sequence that is easily recognized by experts in a particular field of science.

There is a number missing, though. Can you help?

> 57, 86, __, 115, 112, 144, 100, 141, 173, 129, 170, 202, 131, 158, 199, 231, 160, 187

Hint:

> @elias found out that it is chemistry. It is not related to atomic numbers, and is not directly related to the elements- you do not have to knw them to solve this.

Comment: and what's that particular field of science?

Comment: Sorry. You have to guess it.. (Here's a hint: tables)

Comment: @ev3commander I tired running program for equal subset sum problem (Computer Science), no success, yet.

Comment: Actually, the hint should be table, not tables. Also, it's not CS

Comment: Does the sequence have more elements in either direction?

Comment: Yes, to the right, but the objects that the transformed sequence refers to have not been discovered.

Comment: perhaps it is now time to add another hint or answer the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:

> The numbers are orbital shells in order of filling converted from base 29 to base 10. They are: 1s 2s 2p 3s 3p 4s 3d 4p 5s 4d 5p 6s 4f 5d 6p 7s 5f 6d. (Looks like my source didn't have 5f and 6d, sorry, just edited it in) So, the missing number is **83** Source: [Link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pertab/perfill.html)[Link 2](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pertab/perfill.html#c2)

Comment: I think "20" is a typo for "29" here. (And ... seriously, dude, *base 29*? I mean, I understand how you chose it, but that's one seriously weird way to represent them.)

Comment: And this is not directly related to the hint - tables. Also, the electronic configurations are `1s²` `2s²` ... not only 1s and 2s.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi The hint was for the field, not the answer. I thought I made that obvious

Answer (score 0):

Based on the hints (related to a table, not yet discovered objects), I would say this has to do something with

> the periodic table.

However, it is definitely not about

> atomic numbers. At least not directly, as some of the numbers in the question are way too big to be a valid atomic number of currently known chemical elements. Maybe that's where the transformation comes into the picture?

Comment: Yes, it's chemistry, and no, it doesn't directly have to do with elements, and not in any way connected with atomic numbers.